# Access model from controller. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think that i don't understand something.. Why I see "Undefined" in console?

```
  <script>
  function Controller($scope) {
   console.log($scope.name); 
  }  
  </script>

  <body ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
   <input type="text" value="3" ng-model="name">
  </body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Angular does not process the value attribute. If you want to initialize the model value to something in the input, you need to use `ng-init`, f.ex.

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-init="foo = 3">
```

Comment: I seem to have a problem in which my containing controller of a form cannot access the ng-model stated inside the form's input tag. Why is this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code etc., I'd suggest posting a new question and show the relevant pieces of code in it.